# What do clinicians mean by "independent predictor"?

Tags: terminology, predictor

I am a biostatistician and often clinicians use the term "*independent predictor*". For me, it is not clear what exactly is meant by this, and my strategy has so far been to not use the term myself...

I mean in a statistical model, a **predictor** is assumed an **independent variable**. It seams that sometimes "independent predictor" is used for a variable for which a significant association is found in both uni- and multivariable models. Sometimes also in the sense that, there is a significant association, even after controlling for covariates (i.e. multivariable model). Other suggestions are that the term describes significantly associated covariates (besides main effects)...

-> So what?! -> Is this a "pseudo-statistical" term made up by clinicians (searching pubmed for "independent predictor" in title gives >1854 hits)? Or does it have any "real" statistical meaning which I have been ignoring so far?   Any feedback would be higly appreciated!

Comment: I very much empathize with your position! I always interpreted as your second option: " there is a significant association, even after controlling for covariates (i.e. multivariable model)" so independent here means independent of the other predictors we were interested in or could think of.

Comment: ...where independent does not really mean independent in the formal sense of independent events in probability theory, but more like the real life meaning: it doesn't need to rely on the absence (in the model) or presence (in real life) of some other predictors in order to be useful for prediction

Comment: @Vincent: I guess option 2 is probably meant most often. However, what would then be a "dependent predictor"? ;-) Doesn't really add up for me...  Also, the effect size, with this I mean e.g. regression coefficient, of a predictor derived from a multivariable model is **not** independent from the other predictors...

Comment: Perhaps the terms '(potential) explanatory variable' and 'response variable' would be preferable. Although that veers into philosophy about correlation and causation.

Comment: It is indeed veering into philosophy about correlation and causation but I think in this setting a dependent predictor is something that predicts outcome, but 'only' because it is a surrogate for some other predictor not in the model, i.e. it depends on its correlation to the other predictor for its usefulness. But of course nobody would say it like that. Also in the end of course you are right that it doesn't make sense.